# Passing variables between functions in Python, then back to menu

Tags: python, variables

Slowly progressing with my learning with Python and would love a little hand with some code I've tried to create.

I previously had this program running with Global Variables to get a proof of concept to learn about passing variables between functions. Fully worked fine. However, rather than running the function and returning to the menu, it will just stop where I return the value and not progress back to the main menu I created. It is at the point of "return AirportDetailsGlobal".

I'm sure its a simple one, and as said - still learning!
Really appreciate any help on this!

Full code is on pastebin for further reference - pastebin 89VqfwFV

```
      print("\nEnter airport code for overseas")
      osCode = input()
      airports = airData
      for line in airports:
          if osCode in line:
              print (osCode, "Found\n\n")
              print("Airport Name:",line[1])
              OverseaCodeGlobal = osCode
              x = int(line[2])
              AirDataGlobal = x #changed here
              return AirportDetailsGlobal
              break
              
              
              
      else:
          print('Incorrect Choice')
          menu()

      
      menu()
```

Comment: Not enough information in your example. Please read [mre].  You probably need to restructure something so that if a value is returned, the thing that called it has logic to *go back to* the menu.

Comment: Maybe your question goes better here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a `return` then your code goes back to where it was called from. If it wasn't called from anywhere (ie. you just ran that script directly) then calling `return` is in most ways equivalent to calling `sys.exit()`, ie. the program terminates. It'll never hit your break, leave the loop, or hit your call to `menu()`.

Also, your indentation as given there isn't right, the `else` is at the same level as the `for`, not the `if`. I don't think that's the problem but you might hit it next. ;-)